# Is there a way to check wheather the c# program was opened by a file with associated extension?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, streamreader

I want to check if my C# program was opened by a file that has an associated extension. If the program was opened by that file it should execute that function:

```cs
public void openFile(String pathToFile) {
    if (File.Exists(pathToFile)) {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(pathToFile);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
    }
}
```

I've already associated extension.
[image]

Comment: Please explain your question better. Normally, even with a file extension associated, your program needs to do extra work to receive the file name (e.g. as a command line parameter, part of an OLE "open" command, etc.), which would mean you necessarily already know that the file associated is what caused your program to be invoked. Why is that not true in your case? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, explain why the normal approach doesn't work, what exactly you've already tried, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to find the file that was double clicked (or otherwise "executed") which launched your program:

In `program.cs` replace your `static void Main()` with `static void Main(string[] args)`.  This will allow you to see arguments that were passed to your program.  The first argument (`args[0]`) will be the name of the file that was double clicked.

Here's a quick test I wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) MessageBox.Show("args[" + i.ToString() + "]: " + args[i]);
  Application.Run(new Form1(args));
}
```

Comment: ```args[0]``` appears to be null.

Comment: Ok, just wrote a program to test it and it appears to work on my end.  How are you getting your program to execute?  Are you double clicking a file with extension .craftium?

Comment: Related: if you're debugging, you won't have a file to double click to execute your program.  If you want to simulate this go to your project properties, "Debug" tab and write  your custom command line arguments (under "Start Options")

Comment: You can avoid all this by simply checking `var envArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`. Then, `if (envArgs.Length > 1) { ... }`, since `envArgs[0]` always represents the executable path. The registry setting (under `Shell/Open/Command`) should show `%1` after the executable name that opens an associated extension.